# Export Shared Calendar Recurring Events to Excel

Tags: vba, outlook, calendar

I am exporting Outlook calendar data from a shared calendar to Excel. All is working except that my code is exporting the recurred items with their original post date of the series and not for each instance.

I saw a related post "How to show the start date for an INSTANCE of a recurring Series?" but I couldn't make it work.

```vb
Sub Export_Calendar_Final()
    Const SCRIPT_NAME = "Export Calendar to Excel"
    Const xlAscending = 1
    Const xlYes = 1
    Dim olkFld As Object, _
        olkLst As Object, _
        olkRes As Object, _
        olkApt As Object, _
        olkRec As Object, _
        excApp As Object, _
        excWkb As Object, _
        excWks As Object, _
        lngRow As Long, _
        lngCnt As Long, _
        strFil As String, _
        strLst As String, _
        strDat As String, _
        datBeg As Date, _
        datEnd As Date, _
        arrTmp As Variant
    Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
    Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("John Doe")
    Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Set CalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient,     olFolderCalendar)
    Dim CalendarItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Set CalendarItem = CalendarFolder.Items(1)
    CalendarFolder.Items.Sort "[Start]"
    CalendarFolder.Items.IncludeRecurrences = True
       
    datBeg = DateAdd("d", -14, Date)
    datEnd = Date

    Dim RestictStr As String
    RestrictStr = "[Start] >= '" & Format(datBeg, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "' AND [Start] <= '" & Format(datEnd, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"
 
    Set olkRes = CalendarFolder.Items.Restrict(RestrictStr)

    strFil = "I:\Weekly Sales Order Reports\Sales Calendar Export\John Doe.xlsx" 'change folder and file name as needed
      
    Set excApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set excWkb = excApp.Workbooks.Add()
    Set excWks = excWkb.Worksheets(1)
    'Write Excel Column Headers
    With excWks
        .Cells(1, 1) = "Subject"
        .Cells(1, 2) = "Start Date"
        .Cells(1, 3) = "Start Time"
        .Cells(1, 4) = "End Date"
        .Cells(1, 5) = "End Time"
        .Cells(1, 6) = "All day event"
        .Cells(1, 7) = "Required Attendees"
        .Cells(1, 8) = "Categories"
        .Cells(1, 9) = "Hours"
        .Cells(1, 10) = "Location"
        .Cells(1, 11) = "Mailbox"                    
    End With

    lngRow = 2
            
    For Each olkApt In olkRes
        'Only export appointments
        If olkApt.Class = olAppointment Then
            strLst = ""
            For Each olkRec In olkApt.Recipients
                strLst = strLst & olkRec.Name & ", "
            Next

            If strLst <> "" Then strLst = Left(strLst, Len(strLst) - 2)

            'Add a row for each field in the message you want to export
            excWks.Cells(lngRow, 1) = olkApt.Subject
            excWks.Cells(lngRow, 2) = Format(olkApt.Start, "mm/dd/yyyy")
            excWks.Cells(lngRow, 3) = Format(olkApt.Start, "hh:nn:ss")
            excWks.Cells(lngRow, 4) = Format(olkApt.End, "mm/dd/yyyy")
            excWks.Cells(lngRow, 5) = Format(olkApt.End, "hh:nn:ss")
            excWks.Cells(lngRow, 6) = olkApt.AllDayEvent = bolAllDay
            excWks.Cells(lngRow, 7) = strLst
            excWks.Cells(lngRow, 8) = olkApt.Categories
            excWks.Cells(lngRow, 9) = DateDiff("n", olkApt.Start, olkApt.End) / 60
            excWks.Cells(lngRow, 9).NumberFormat = "0.00"
            excWks.Cells(lngRow, 10) = olkApt.Location
            excWks.Cells(lngRow, 11) = "John Doe"
            lngRow = lngRow + 1
            lngCnt = lngCnt + 1
        End If
    Next
    excWks.Columns("A:H").AutoFit
    excWkb.SaveAs "I:\Weekly Sales Order Reports\Sales Calendar Export\John Doe.xlsx"
    excWkb.Close
            
    Set excWks = Nothing
    Set excWkb = Nothing
    Set excApp = Nothing
    Set olkApt = Nothing
    Set olkLst = Nothing
    Set olkFld = Nothing
            
    MsgBox "Process complete.  A total of " & lngCnt & " appointments were exported.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, SCRIPT_NAME

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is: there is only one entry in a calendar folder for a recurring item and you are not interrogating any of the recurring item properties.

If you seek one entry per recurrence in your worksheet, you will have to generate them.  You will need an end date unless you want “for ever” entries to recur until the year 4500 and a sort of the worksheet after you have finished processing all the calendar items.

I do not remember the circumstances in which I coded the macro below.  It is clearly an investigation of calendar items and not an attempt to create pretty output.  I place a `Debug.Assert False` statement at the top of every path through my code and comment those statements out as I encounter them.  I appear to have generated test entries for most of the different types of recurrence although the comment `Have not thought repeating multi-day appointments through` suggests not all.

I have updated line 12 to address my current desktop so this code works with Office 2016 and Windows 10 as well as the much older versions for which it was written. You will need to update line 12 to address a folder on your system.

Try this code with your shared calendar then mine it for the functionality you need to update your code.

```
Option Explicit
Sub DspCalandarItems()

  Dim ItemCrnt As Object
  Dim ItemCrntClass As Long
  Dim FileOut As Object
  Dim FolderSrc As MAPIFolder
  Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
  Dim RecurrPattCrnt As RecurrencePattern

  Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set FileOut = FSO.CreateTextFile("c:\users\Admin\Desktop\Appointments.txt", True)

  With GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set FolderSrc = .GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    FileOut.WriteLine ("Number of items: " & FolderSrc.Items.Count)

    For Each ItemCrnt In FolderSrc.Items

      With ItemCrnt

        ' Occasionally I get syncronisation
        ' errors.  This code avoids them.
        ItemCrntClass = 0
        On Error Resume Next
        ItemCrntClass = .Class
        On Error GoTo 0

        ' I have never found anything but appointments in
        ' Calendar but test just in case
        If ItemCrntClass = olAppointment Then

          Select Case .RecurrenceState
            Case olApptException
              FileOut.WriteLine ("Recurrence state is Exception")
              If .AllDayEvent Then
                FileOut.WriteLine ("All day " & Format(.Start, "ddd d mmm yy"))
                Debug.Assert False
              ElseIf Day(.Start) = Day(.End) Then
                ' Appointment starts and finishes on same day
                If Format(.Start, "hh:mm") <> Format(.End, "hh:mm") Then
                  ' Different start and end times on same day
                  FileOut.Write ("From " & Format(.Start, "hh:mm") & " to " & _
                                           Format(.End, "hh:mm") & " on " & Format(.Start, "ddd d mmm yy"))
                  Debug.Assert False
                Else
                  ' Start and end time the same
                  Debug.Assert False
                  FileOut.Write ("At " & Format(.Start, "hh:mm") & " on " & Format(.Start, "ddd d mmm yy"))
                End If
              Else
                ' Different start and end dates.
                FileOut.Write ("From " & Format(.Start, "hh:mm") & " on " & Format(.Start, "ddd d mmm yy") & " to " & _
                                         Format(.End, "hh:mm") & " on " & Format(.End, "ddd d mmm yy"))
              End If
              Debug.Assert False
            Case olApptMaster
              Set RecurrPattCrnt = .GetRecurrencePattern
              Debug.Assert Year(RecurrPattCrnt.PatternStartDate) = Year(.Start)
              Debug.Assert Month(RecurrPattCrnt.PatternStartDate) = Month(.Start)
              Debug.Assert Day(RecurrPattCrnt.PatternStartDate) = Day(.Start)
              If .AllDayEvent Then
                FileOut.Write ("All day ")
              ElseIf Day(.Start) = Day(.End) Then
                Debug.Assert False
                ' Appointment starts and finishes on same day
                If Format(.Start, "hh:mm") <> Format(.End, "hh:mm") Then
                  ' Different start and end times on same day
                  FileOut.Write ("From " & Format(.Start, "hh:mm") & " to " & _
                                           Format(.End, "hh:mm") & " ")
                  Debug.Assert False
                Else
                  ' Start and end time the same
                  FileOut.Write ("At " & Format(.Start, "hh:mm") & " ")
                  Debug.Assert False
                End If
              ElseIf DateDiff("d", .Start, .End) = 1 And Format(.Start, "hh:mm") = "00:00" And _
                                                         Format(.End, "hh:mm") = "00:00" Then
                FileOut.Write ("All day ")
                'Debug.Assert False
              Else
                ' Have not thought repeating multi-day appointments through
                Debug.Assert False
                FileOut.Write ("XXX From " & Format(.Start, "hh:mm") & " on " & Format(.Start, "ddd d mmm yy") & " to " & _
                                         Format(.End, "hh:mm") & " on " & Format(.End, "ddd d mmm yy"))
              End If
              Select Case RecurrPattCrnt.RecurrenceType
                Case olRecursDaily
                  FileOut.Write ("daily")
                Case olRecursMonthly
                Case olRecursMonthNth
                  FileOut.Write ("nth monthly")
                Case olRecursWeekly
                  FileOut.Write ("weekly")
                  Debug.Assert False
                Case olRecursYearly
                  'Debug.Assert False
                  FileOut.Write ("yearly")
              End Select  ' RecurrPattCrnt.RecurrenceType
              FileOut.Write (" from " & Format(RecurrPattCrnt.PatternStartDate, "ddd d mmm yy"))
              If Year(RecurrPattCrnt.PatternEndDate) = 4500 Then
                ' For ever
                'Debug.Assert False
              Else
                FileOut.Write (" to " & Format(RecurrPattCrnt.PatternEndDate, "ddd d mmm yy"))
                'Debug.Assert False
              End If
            Case olApptNotRecurring
              If .AllDayEvent Then
                FileOut.Write ("All day " & Format(.Start, "ddd d mmm yy"))
                'Debug.Assert False
              ElseIf Day(.Start) = Day(.End) Then
                ' Appointment starts and finishes on same day
                If Format(.Start, "hh:mm") <> Format(.End, "hh:mm") Then
                  ' Different start and end times on same day
                  FileOut.Write ("From " & Format(.Start, "hh:mm") & " to " & _
                                           Format(.End, "hh:mm") & " on " & Format(.Start, "ddd d mmm yy"))
                  'Debug.Assert False
                Else
                  ' Start and end time the same
                  FileOut.Write ("At " & Format(.Start, "hh:mm") & " on " & Format(.Start, "ddd d mmm yy"))
                  'Debug.Assert False
                End If
              Else
                ' Different start and end dates.
                FileOut.Write ("From " & Format(.Start, "hh:mm") & " on " & Format(.Start, "ddd d mmm yy") & " to " & _
                                         Format(.End, "hh:mm") & " on " & Format(.End, "ddd d mmm yy"))
                'Debug.Assert False
              End If
            Case olApptOccurrence
              FileOut.WriteLine ("Occurrence")
              Debug.Assert False
            Case Else
              Debug.Print ("Unknown recurrence state " & .RecurrenceState)
              Debug.Assert False
              FileOut.WriteLine ("Unknown recurrence state " & .RecurrenceState)
          End Select  ' .RecurrenceState
          If .Subject <> "" Then
            FileOut.Write ("  " & .Subject)
          Else
            FileOut.Write ("  ""No subject""")
          End If
          If .Location <> "" Then
            FileOut.Write (" at " & .Location)
          Else
            FileOut.Write (" at undefined location")
          End If
          FileOut.WriteLine ("")
          If .Body <> "" Then
            FileOut.WriteLine ("  Body: " & .Body)
          End If

        End If ' ItemCrntClass = olAppointment

      End With  ' ItemCrnt

    Next ItemCrnt

  End With  ' GetNamespace("MAPI")

  FileOut.Close

End Sub
```